# Use mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Tags: laravel-5

The error is that i can't use a loop
foreach or for with this package mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf to generate a PDF

```
 $pdf->addPage(
            '<html>
                <HEAD>
                    <TITLE>Acta de Recepcion</TITLE>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                </HEAD>
                <body>
                    <?php 
                        @foreach ($due as $d)
                            {{$d->placa}}
                        @endforeach
                     ?>
                </body> 
            </html>');
```

i need use a foreach to add dates dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try it a different way:

```
// build the content
$content = '<html>
                <HEAD>
                    <TITLE>Acta de Recepcion</TITLE>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                </HEAD>
                <body>';

// add the dates
foreach ($due as $d) {
    $content .= $d->placa;
}

// complete the content
$content .= '</body> 
            </html>';

// add the page
$pdf->addPage($content);
```